# Jquery Ajax request Call multiple times using loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, loops, asynchronous

I need to perform one task in jQuery/JavaScript using a loop. I need to call a loop 10 times, and in each iteration, I need to make an Ajax call. In each iteration, I also need to check a condition in the response of the Ajax call. If the condition is met, then the next iteration should continue, prompting the user with a confirmation box. Otherwise, the loop should end. I kindly request your assistance with this.

```
 function GetNextBagWeight() {
    let res = "OK";
    var arr = [];
    $.ajax({
        url: '/LoadingControl/GetNextBagWeight?BayId=' + 1,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(response, status, xhr) {
            debugger
            var trHTML = '';
            var count = 1;
            if (response.isSuucess) {
                trHTML = '<tr><td>' + count + '</td><td>' +
                    response.BagWeight + "</td><td>" +
                    CurrentDateWithTimeString() + "</td></tr>";
                $('#tblRunTimeBagData').append(trHTML);
                resp = "OK";
                arr.push("OK")
            } else {
                trHTML = '<tr style="background-color: red;"><td>' + count + '</td><td>' +
                    response.BagWeight + "</td><td>" +
                    CurrentDateWithTimeString() + "</td></tr>";
                $('#tblRunTimeBagData').append(trHTML);
                arr.push("wait")
                if (confirm('Proceed')) {
                    alert('Thanks for confirming, start next iteration');
                }
            }
        }
    });
    
    return res;
}
```

Everything is fine here; the confirmation popup also appears. However, the Ajax call in the background is still happening for the next iterations, which should only occur after clicking the confirmation button.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to promisify the AJAX call. Read this article: https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-promisify-an-ajax-call/

This is a promisified version of an AJAX call:

```
function doTheThing() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
      url: window.location.href,
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        key: 'value',
      },
      success: function (data) {
        resolve(data)
      },
      error: function (error) {
        reject(error)
      },
    })
  })
}
```

Note that:

- a Promise is returned
- which is resolved on success
- and rejected on failure

And she provides this usage example:

```
doTheThing()
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
    doSomethingElse()
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

Now, you want to make it customizable and chained, a promise becoming the prerequisite for the next:

```
function doTheThing(url, type, data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: type,
      data: data,
      success: function (data) {
        resolve(data)
      },
      error: function (error) {
        reject(error)
      },
    })
  })
}
```

So, let's suppose you have an array of AJAX calls to make, then:

```
let currentPromise = undefined;
for (let index = 0; index < myPromises.length; index++) {
    let prom = doTheThing(myPromises[index].url, myPromises[index].type, myPromises[index].data);
    if (!currentPromise) {
        currentPromise = prom;
    } else {
        currentPromise = currentPromise.then(prom);
    }
}
```